# css fit 2 elements to 100% width

Tags: css, compass-sass

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>field 1</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>field 2</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>field 3</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

How can I make a label-input pair use 100% of the width with CSS ? (and each pair be on their own line)

I used to put the label-input pair in a sub div of their own. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with just CSS. (I'm using compass to generate the CSS).

For bonus points .. can you have the same CSS make the label a line above on mobile (small screen) devices.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: This is like the closest I got .. http://jsfiddle.net/LdaVL/ .. but I don't expect it to be very robust if the page size changes with those percents :(

Comment: Tweek the label width a bit and this may be your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of like this? http://jsfiddle.net/m6pZH/13/

---

I suggest you modify your HTML slightly, as it will be hard (if even possible) to properly maintain your current HTML properly:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>field 1</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>field 2</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <label>field 3</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

li > label {
    float: left;
}

li > input {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. but I want to see if it's possible without modifying the html .. so no <ul> and <li> allowed :)

Comment: Chose the answer due to the link http://jsfiddle.net/m6pZH/3/ which definitely puts me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div label, div input {
    display: block;
}
```

displaying elements on `block` puts them on their own line and makes them a block element.

Edited content:

```
div { width: 600px }
div label { float: left; width: 200px; }
div input { float: right: width: 390px; }
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks. That kind of puts the label on 1 line .. then the input on the next .. I would like each pair to be on the same line.

Comment: Thanks again @Indranil .. still not looking like I would like .. http://jsfiddle.net/MbDyy/ - it would be great if there could be a 'liquid' solution .. even if it dumps IE6 browser

Comment: Added a wrapping of `<p></p>` around the inputs.